# Android error wen inflating custom view

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-layout, android-custom-view

I am trying to use this plugin to display zoomable images.

https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView

I have imported it in eclipse, and referenced it in my project properties. This is my xml:

The custom view is `com.example.touch.TouchImageView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   style="@style/RegularView"  
   android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <com.example.touch.TouchImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/prev_button"
            android:contentDescription="@string/fish_cd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_previous_item" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/next_button"
            android:contentDescription="@string/fish_cd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_next_item" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/comment"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true" 
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

         <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/page"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/admin_controls"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="horizontal" >

             <CheckBox
                 android:id="@+id/switch1"
                 android:layout_gravity="center"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:text="@string/main" />

             <CheckBox
                 android:id="@+id/switch2"
                 android:layout_gravity="center"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:text="@string/approved" />

             <Button
                 android:id="@+id/delete_button"
                 android:layout_gravity="center"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:text="@string/delete"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I start the activity, it crashes with:

```
08-07 17:07:09.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2106): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-07 17:07:09.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2106): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{android.arin/android.arin.GalleryScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.example.touch.TouchImageView
08-07 17:07:09.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2106):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
08-07 17:07:09.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2106):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
08-07 17:07:09.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2106):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
08-07 17:07:09.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2106):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
08-07 17:07:09.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2106):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-07 17:07:09.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2106):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-07 17:07:09.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2106):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
08-07 17:07:09.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2106):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-07 17:07:09.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2106):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-07 17:07:09.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2106):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
08-07 17:07:09.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2106):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
08-07 17:07:09.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2106):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-07 17:07:09.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2106): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.example.touch.TouchImageView
08-07 17:07:09.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2106):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
08-07 17:07:09.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2106):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
08-07 17:07:09.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2106):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
08-07 17:07:09.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2106):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
08-07 17:07:09.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2106):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
08-07 17:07:09.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2106):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
08-07 17:07:09.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2106):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:316)
08-07 17:07:09.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2106):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1915)
08-07 17:07:09.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2106):     at android.arin.GalleryScreen.onCreate(GalleryScreen.java:44)
08-07 17:07:09.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2106):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5177)
08-07 17:07:09.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2106):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
08-07 17:07:09.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2106):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
08-07 17:07:09.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2106):     ... 11 more
08-07 17:07:09.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2106): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.touch.TouchImageView
08-07 17:07:09.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2106):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
08-07 17:07:09.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2106):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
08-07 17:07:09.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2106):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
08-07 17:07:09.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2106):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
08-07 17:07:09.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2106):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
08-07 17:07:09.340: E/AndroidRuntime(2106):     ... 22 more
```

Does anyone know whats wrong here?

Thanks

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try running a clean solution, and try it again I've seen this many many times before and usually is a reference issue, or some issue in the xml file itself.. ie: non closing matching tags. etc.

It says the class cannot be found,  try restarting eclipse and/or check the reference again.

Comment: I fixed it. In the xml it says `<com.example.touch.TouchImageView`, but really it should be `<com.ortiz.touch.TouchImageView`. This is actually a mistake on the github website. On the homepage api, it says to put `example` but when you download the code, it needs to be `ortiz`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is with your TouchImageView path.

If your CustomView have file inside your src package, then use that path.

For example,  Let's say your package name is `com.example.touch.someapp` and if the TouchImageView file is in this package then use like below.

```
 <com.example.touch.someapp.TouchImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

But, If you are linking a project, then it should be exact path where CustomView is present.

For your example, if you are linking the project from

https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView, then your view should be like below

```
 <com.ortiz.touch.TouchImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Please let me know if it works.